# How to pass a getter or a class attribute to symfony custom constraint?

Tags: symfony, validation, annotations, constraints

I have a custom constraint to validate if given coordinates are inside a given region, but i'm not able to pass this regionId to the constraint cause it's not a constant, it's a class variable.
I've tried this

    `/**
     * @var array
     * @CoordinatesInsideRegion(regionId= getRegionId())
     */
    protected $coordinates;`

    But it's returning this

> {"code":500,"message":"[Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant getRegionId, property CustomerBundle\DTO\Address\Request\CreateAddressRequestDTO::$coordinates."}

I've also tried regionId, this.regionId, this.getRegionId()
And none worked

Comment: Update your custom validator to target class instead of property, then you will get entire object as value. See this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator

Comment: @GasKa i was trying to avoid this solution, why send the whole class when you only need two fields, but seems like there's no other way. Thank you